# How can I see all docker Image tags?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-tag

I am pretty new to docker and I started playing around with it.

I downloaded the latest mongo docker image: `docker pull mongo`
Then I view the image I downloaded (`docker images`) but the only information i have regarding the version of mongo is the tag which is just 'latest'

I found that I can use the `docker inspect` command to determine the version, which did prove helpful, but it is also very inconvenient.

since I read that each Image can have multiple tags, I am assuming the mongo image I downloaded has another tag with the version number.

How can I view all tags of an image I downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use registry api to do it, reference to [this](https://fordodone.com/2015/10/02/docker-get-list-of-tags-in-repository/) & [this](http://www.googlinux.com/list-all-tags-of-docker-image/index.html).

For your case, you can just use next command:

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/mongo/tags -O -  | sed -e 's/[][]//g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ //g' | tr '}' '\n'  | awk -F: '{print $3}'
```

Change the `mongo` to others if you need tags of other images.

Comment: is there a way to correlate tags? For Instance to see which tags are the same as `latest`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see all the tags available for one image, you need to check on the registry where your image is stored. In your case, you're using the default public registry which you can find [here](https://hub.docker.com/).

You can find all the mongo tags, directly [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=tags).
In the *description* tab, you'll also see that, currently, the **latest** tag is also associated with the versions **4.0.10, 4.0** and **4**.

Furthermore, in order to get a specific tag, you need to use this command:

```
docker image pull image:tag
```

For example, if you want to pull the version **4.0.10** of mongo then you need to type :

```
docker image pull mongo:4.0.10
```

Answer (score 1):

You just downloaded one tag. in your case `latest` which is an alias to one other tag, most of the times but not always the highest version number. In this Case it's `4, 4.0` and `4.0.10` which are all the same images. But there is an even newer image which is released `unstable` and which is `4.1`.

The mongo tags you can find [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=tags). It's always a good idea to check the dockerhub description of the images, there you will find a lot of information.